# How to use a javascript project in our node project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

As I'm beginning to grasp the world of javascript as a client/server language (up to now it's all been C#), I would like to know how could I have an existing project as part of my own project so I can call it internally and not after it's loaded in the client.

using [js-cookie project](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), and taken that I have:

```
/libs
  app.ts
/dependencies
  js-cookie.js
/dist
 app.js
gruntfile.js
server.js
package.json
```

I would love to do:

```
import * as JsCookies from './../dependencies/js-cookie.js'

export default class MyProject {

    get_cookie(name: string):string {
        return JsCookie.get(name);
    }

    set_cookie(name: string, value: string, expires?: number): void {
        if (typeof expires === "number")
            JsCookie.set(name, value, { expires: expires });
        else
            JsCookie.set(name, value);
    }

    // ...
}
```

in short, **abstract my own project** of handling cookies and use the **js-cookie project** for that, and let webpack minimize it and obfuscating it.

How could I achieve such thing?

Comment: if you downvote, say at least why ...

Comment: I would say you take some time to read about client server, what webpack and node.js are/do first. :)

Comment: @toskv as I said, I'm still grasping on it all... I came from a very different background,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

in a terminal:

```
$ npm install js-cookie
```

Then in your code:

```
var Cookies = require('js-cookie');
Cookies.set(...);
```

**Old irreleveant stuff:**

As far as I can understand what you want to do, you'll have to export the class.

```
// your class definition
var foo = function() {
};

module.exports = foo;
```

Then, in your other file, just do:

```
var Foo = require('./../dependencies/js-cookie.js');
var bar = new Foo();
bar.get(...);
bar.set(...);
```

Update:

In the end, `module.exports` is the key to export data, functions, classes through node.

Comment: it's a weird file: [https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/blob/master/src/js.cookie.js](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/blob/master/src/js.cookie.js) ... hate to think I have to edit it everytime it updates

Comment: I see! I thought it was some code you or your team wrote.
Then, from the github page, they say they support npm. So have a look to my updated answer, and it should work.

Comment: I think it's what you said, using the npm version and no worries about anything else... darn me, always trying to complicate the simple things :)

Comment: Well, you have to adapt to the node paradigm.
Also, I find js.cookie's documentation page vague about node implementation. Usually, you'll find the bash commands.

Have fun with node, and as you come from C#, try to go with Typescript (superset of Javascript), you'll find to be more at home.

Comment: as you can see from the file `app.ts` and the definitions `(name: string, ...` I already use typescript :) makes the change so much easier, eheheh